# Show list items in AngularJS ng-grid

Tags: splistitem, angularjs

retrieving SharePoint list items by REST with

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);

    app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $http.get('http://whereever/_api/web/lists/getByTitle("Tasks")/items').success(function (data) {
            $scope.items = data;
        });

        $scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'items',
            columnDefs: [
            { field: 'Title', displayName: 'Title' },
            { field: 'Status', displayName: 'Status' }
            ]
        };
    });
```

the ng-grid on

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
    </div>
```

just shows nothing. A simple json example like 
http://plnkr.co/edit/UndbtO?p=preview
works. Is there any example showing me how to use a REST call on a SharePoint list and passing data to ng-grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
var myAngApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
myAngApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {   
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "http://whereever/_api/web/lists/getByTitle("Tasks")/items",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.items = data.d.results;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {   
        console.log(status);
    });

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'items',
        columnDefs: [
        { field: 'Title', displayName: 'Title' },
        { field: 'Status', displayName: 'Status' }
        ]
    };

});
```